# Lucene 3.0.3 Numeric term query

Tags: java, lucene

I have a numeric field in Lucene 3.0.3 and it works perfectly fine with the range queries. If we switch to the TermQuery it doesnt produce any result. For example:

```
    Document doc = new Document();
    String name = "geolongitude";
    NumericField numericField = new NumericField(name);
    double value = 29.0753505;
    String valueAsString = "29.0753505";
    numericField.setDoubleValue(value);
    doc.add(numericField);
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
    indexWriter.commit();
    indexWriter.close();
    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(open);
    Query termQ = new TermQuery(new Term(name, valueAsString));
    TopDocs search = indexSearcher.search(termQ, 10);
```

In this case I dont get any result. I tried to figure out whether exist any "NumericTermQuery" but couldnt find that. I could do something tricky (make a range query for the term that I am searching) but I dont like the solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figure out a different solution,

```
String doubleToPrefixCoded = NumericUtils.doubleToPrefixCoded(value);
Query termQ = new TermQuery(new Term(name, doubleToPrefixCoded));
```

I found it out from : http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/88516 and it works correctly

Comment: Yes, this can work, but I find that using `NumericUtils` directly is not the best idea.  Problem is, as noted in the API: "NOTE: This API is for internal purposes only and might change in incompatible ways in the next release.".  It can change significantly and incompatibly across versions, and has (especially in 4.0).  It also requires you to worry about possible precision related errors, since you must generate *exactly* the same term, rather than allowing `NumericRangeQuery`'s precision handling to take over that concern.

Answer (score 6):

Numeric fields are not indexed as plain text terms, so searching for their string representation as a term won't work.

Like it or not, constructing a `NumericRangeQuery` where min = max is indeed the correct approach:

```
Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(name, value, value, true, true);
```

The implementation of `NumericRangeQuery` recognizes this case specifically, actually, and is designed to handle it well.

Comment: Well, I have figure out another answer, and it is working. So obviously this is not the only possible query. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

When you built index with NumericField, the value in index is 29.0753505 (a double data). The TermQuery will use the value "29.0753505"(a String) to search.

I think if you don't like use the range query, you can imply a numeric query by yourself, and you can see the code of `NumericRangeTermEnum` in `NumericRangeQuery`, and imply one that make the termEnum contains all terms that exactly matched.