# How to match numeric and boolean values in a lucene query

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search, hibernate-5.x

I am using hibernate search to construct a lucene query that returns string values that contain (part of) the search string. Next to that the query must only return the string values if the language id matches as well and if the deleted flag isn't set to true. I've made the below code for this. But the problem is that it doesn't return anything.

```
private Query getQueryWithBooleanClauses(Class entityClass, String searchString, Long preferredLanguageId, FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager, String firstField, String... additionalFields) {
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = getQueryBuilder(entityClass, fullTextEntityManager);
    Query containsSearchString = getMatchingStringCondition(searchString, queryBuilder, firstField, additionalFields);
    BooleanQuery isPreferredOrDefaultLanguageTranslation = getLanguageCondition(preferredLanguageId);
    BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(new TermQuery(new Term("parentDeleted", "false")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .add(new TermQuery(new Term("parentApproved", "true")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .add(new TermQuery(new Term("childDeleted", "false")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .add(isPreferredOrDefaultLanguageTranslation, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .add(containsSearchString, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .build();
    return finalQuery;
}
```

getMatchingStringCondition

```
private Query getMatchingStringCondition(String searchString, QueryBuilder queryBuilder, String firstField, String... additionalFields) {
    log.info(MessageFormat.format("{0}*", searchString));
    return queryBuilder.simpleQueryString()
            .onFields(firstField, additionalFields)
            .withAndAsDefaultOperator()
            .matching(MessageFormat.format("{0}*", searchString))
            .createQuery();
}
```

getLanguageCondition

```
private BooleanQuery getLanguageCondition(Long preferredLanguageId) {
    return new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(createLanguagePredicate(preferredLanguageId), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(createLanguagePredicate(languageService.getDefaultLanguage().getId()), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .build();
}
```

createLanguagePredicate

```
private Query createLanguagePredicate(Long languageId){
    return new TermQuery(new Term("language.languageId", languageId.toString()));
}
```

Query executing method

```
public List<AutoCompleteSuggestion> findAllBySearchStringAndDeletedIsFalse(Class entityClass, String searchString, Long preferredLanguageId){
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    Query finalQuery = getQueryWithBooleanClauses(entityClass, searchString, preferredLanguageId, fullTextEntityManager, "parent.latinName", "translatedName");
    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(finalQuery, entityClass);
    fullTextQuery.setProjection("parentId", "autoCompleteSuggestion", "childApproved"); //volgorde moet overeen komen met argumenten volgorde in AutoCompleteSuggestion constructor, zie convertToAutoCompleteSuggestionList
    fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    fullTextQuery.getResultList();
return convertToAutoCompleteSuggestionList(fullTextQuery.getResultList());
}
```

This code doesn't throw an error but never returns anything either. Only when i remove all the boolean conditions for the boolean and numerical fields, leaving only the `containsSearchString` condition will the query return anything.

According to this post [Hibernate Search 5.0 Numeric Lucene Query HSEARCH000233 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138308/hibernate-search-5-0-numeric-lucene-query-hsearch000233-issue) this happens because as of Hibernate search 5 numerical fields are no longer treated as text fields and you can't perform matching queries on numerical fields.

You can force that the fields are treated as textfields by annotating them with `@FieldBridge`. But i'd rather not do that. So my question is. How do i perform match queries on non-text fields like booleans, dates, and numbers?

EDIT: It works if i annotate all the fields required for filtering with `@FieldBridge`(impl= implementation.class)`,also the index parameter must always be set to YES.

But now all these fields will be stored as strings, which is undesirable. So i'd still like to know if there is another more elegant way to apply filters.

EDIT 2:

@yrodiere, When i removed `@FieldBridge(impl = LongBridge.class)` from `languageId` and replace the line `.add(isPreferredOrDefaultLanguageTranslation, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)` with:

`.add(queryBuilder.bool().must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("language.languageId").matching(languageService.getDefaultLanguage().getId().toString()).createQuery()).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)`

I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000238: Cannot create numeric range query for field 'language.languageId', since values are not numeric (Date, int, long, short or double)
```

However just now i discovered that `matching()` also accepts a `Long` number so i don't have to call `toString()` on it. When `matching()` uses the `Long` value i don't get an error but nothing is returned either.

Only when i used `new TermQuery(new Term("language.languageId", languageId.toString()))` instead of `matching()` while also using a `LongBridge` for `languageId` will anything get returned. Am i defining the `matching()` query erroneously?

I also have a different question that i wanted to start a new SO question for. But maybe you can answer that question in this thread as well :). The question is about the `includeEmbeddedObjectId` parameter of `@IndexedEmbedded`. I think i know what this does but i would like to have some confirmation from you.

I assume that when i set this to `true` the id of the parent entity will be included in the lucene document of the child entity, correct? Lets say that this parent entity is used in a `matching()` query thats used as a `true/false` condition. Is it then correct to assume that the search will be faster because the id can now also be found in the lucene document of the child entity?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding `includeEmbeddedObjectId`: it includes the id of entities targeted by the association in the embedded object. So if `MyIndexedEntity` has a property `@ManyToOne Language language`, and you put `@IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)` on that property, and the ID of the `Language` entity is called `languageId`, you will get a new field `language.languageId` in the index of `MyIndexedEntity`. That field will be automatically populated with... the language id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booleans are still indexed as strings in Hibernate Search 5. See `org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.BooleanBridge`. So boolean fields are not  part of the problem here.

If you really want to create numeric queries yourself, in Hibernate Search 5 you will have to use numeric range queries, e.g.:

```java
private Query createLanguagePredicate(Long languageId){
    return org.apache.lucene.search.NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("language.languageId", languageId, 
languageId, true, true);
}
```

That being said, to avoid that kind of problems, you should use the [Hibernate Search DSL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl). Then you'll pass values of the type you use in your model (here, a `Long`), and Hibernate Search will create the right query automatically.

Or even better, upgrade to [Hibernate Search 6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/), which exposes a different API, but less verbose and with fewer quirks. See for yourself in the [documentation of the Search DSL in Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl), in particular the [predicate DSL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-predicate).

Comment: @yorodiere i'm already using Hibernate search DSL. In your example you're using a numeric range query. But my problem concerns comparing the values of `language.languageId` to some number. When i try to use `matching()` for this i get an exception because the field is numeric and you can only use `matching()`on string fields. Is there a `matching()` variant for numeric fields?

Comment: "you can only use matching() on string field" => That's not true? At least not with the `keyword()` query, which you should be using in this case. If you have a question about different code than what you showed in your question, then please add that code to your question. I can't guess what's going wrong without at least looking at the code.

Comment: i've added some extra information to my question, @yrodiere. It starts under `EDIT 2:`.

Comment: Regarding your second edit... Did you make sure to [reindex your data](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer) after changing your mapping (removing the bridge)? Because changing the type of a field definitely requires reindexing. Without that, you are likely to get the behavior you're getting, i.e. no matches at all.

Comment: Everything is in working order now @yrodiere. Many thanks!